# How to calculate an `InverseMellinTransform` up to its definition in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex, integral-transforms

I have a question about how to calculate Inverse Mellin Transformation's in Mathematica, one way or the other.

Look at these findings.

The following integral results in Gamma[s].

```
Integrate[x^(s - 1) E^-x, {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {Re[s] > 0}]
```

The same, but using MellinTransform also results in Gamma[s], as expected, of course.

```
MellinTransform[E^-x, x, s]
```

Using InverseMellinTransform results, as expected, in E^{-x}

```
InverseMellinTransform[Gamma[s], s, x]
```

But using the definition of Inverse Mellin Transformation does not reply with an answer.

```
1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[x^-s Gamma[s], {s, -I Infinity, I Infinity}]
```

My question is, if I can calculate Inverse Mellin Transformations using the classical way in Mathematica, because very few InverseMellinTransform's actually work..., like this one for example.

```
In[32]:= InverseMellinTransform[Zeta[s]^4/Zeta[2 s], s, x]
```

Comment: This is rather math, than Mathematica. In any case, one cannot integrate along the imaginary axis, when calculating `InverseMellinTransform`, since `Gamma[z]` has a pole at the origin (see the documentation to `InverseMellinTransform` for info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment. According to [that question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414290/mellin-transform-of-powers-of-gamma-function) and [that book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LtOfHnClUSEC&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=the+Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin+integral.&source=bl&ots=s6bYPQ4Jal&sig=ACfU3U39ij7KD-jHgYxYHug66q6CEtlR0A&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizi9eTj6X2AhUS66QKHYWbBYoQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=the%20Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin%20integral.&f=false), the relation (with $a>0$)  $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{\operatorname{Res}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{a-i\infty}^{a+i \infty}\varGamma(z) x^{-z}\,dz=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\Res_{z=-m}\Gamma(z)x^{-z} $$ holds.

Mathematica is able to calculate the RHS by

```
Sum[Assuming[m \[Element] Integers && m >= 0, 
Residue[Gamma[z]*x^(-z), {z, -m}]], {m, 0, Infinity}]
```

> `E^-x`

Comment: Looks good. Thank you, so much. Will investigate. Up voted, and accept follows after investigation. Thanks for answering.

Comment: You most probably recognized what I am working on, the point is that I want to calculate in some way: InverseMellinTransform[Log[Zeta[s]]/s, s, x] ; Do you think that is possible? - ( Sorry for the late reply but with a war close by, priorities change unexpectedly. Although personally I am still safe. But for how long, I do not know. )